# Check from within parent if nested route is active

Tags: ember.js

Inside my router I have `parent route` and then there is a `child route` nested under the `parent route`. `Parent template` contains `{{outlet}}` to render the `child template` once the user navigates to the `child route`.

Is it possible to set a property inside `parent controller` which will check wether the `parent` or nested route is active? Or is there any way to tell if `outlet` has any nested content loaded in it? Later I want to use the property inside `parent template` to give user feedback wether the `parent` or nested route is active.

Comment: May been you can add an observer to the 'currentPath' or 'currentRouteName' in the application controller and do something based on its value.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a addEventListener to parent route to listen specific event you are interested in and pass on necessary feedback by updating a property on respective controller. Will try to create a jsbin.